# It seems that I can't read .rdf file into OntModel (.rdfs and .owl is okay.)

Tags: model, rdf, jena

```
public class List_subPropertyOf {

//static final String inputFileName = "data/dbpedia_3.9.owl";
//static final String inputFileName = "data/wnfull.rdfs";
static final String inputFileName = "data/lov.rdf"; 

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        //create the reasoning model using the base
        OntModel inf = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();

        // use the FileManager to find the input file
        InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName);

        File logFile = new File("List_subPropertyOf.txt");
        PrintStream logPrintStream = new PrintStream(logFile);
        System.setOut(logPrintStream);

        if (in == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
        }

        inf.read(in, "", "RDF/XML");

        ExtendedIterator properties = inf.listOntProperties();
        while (properties.hasNext()) {


            OntProperty essaProperty = (OntProperty) properties.next();

            System.out.println("Property: " + essaProperty.getLocalName());
            for (Iterator i = essaProperty.listSubProperties(); i.hasNext();) {
                OntProperty c = (OntProperty) i.next();
                System.out.print("   " + c.getLocalName() + "\n");
            } // end for
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Exception:
Please see the picture.
How could I do? I don't have enough reputation to post a picture. And I can't post an exception with more than 2 links but my exception has...

16:55:37 WARN  OntDocumentManager        :: An error occurred while attempting to read from http://www.ontotext.com/proton/protontop. Msg was 'org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.'.
com.hp.hpl.jena.shared.JenaException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Answer (score 1):

What's referring to http://www.ontotext.com/proton/protontop? Is it data/lov.rdf?

If you are using older versions of Jena, it will ask for RDF/XML, but that URL returns Turtle whatever you ask for which isn't handled.  Newer versions have changed this.

Otherwise, sample data and a full stack trace would help.